# Book about a school girl, unaware of the fact that she's a robot who kills while she's asleep

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

I read this book a couple of years ago. I believe it was about a girl who went to a school in a really futuristic world and tries to find a killer. Later on, it's revealed that she is a robot and is the killer in her sleep. I also vaguely remember a part about a bomb in the principal's office and her trying to run away.

Comment: This brings "Fondly Fahrenheit" by Bester to mind, but that is clearly not a match.